# Which API is called by the Windows taskbar to set its position in Windows 7?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, operating-system, taskbar

I would like to know which which API is called by the system to set the taskbar position, specially for Windows 7.

In non-Windows 7, the OS `GetMonitorinfo()` is called by the system to set the taskbar position.

What function is used in Windows 7?

Comment: When `explorer.exe` starts up it reads the contents of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects2` to decide where the taskbar should be. Maybe someone else has reverse engineered the API call or message to change it at runtime.

Comment: SHAppBarMessage() controls the taskbar position.  On all recent Windows versions, not just 7.